# How to search "info" page for keyword

Tags: linux, search, info

I'm currently looking through the "info" page for "ls" command and I want to find all relevant sections that contain the keyword "-l". But I'm not sure how to search for keywords and how to move between different instance of same keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inside an info page e.g  "info python" press the / key and it will give you prompt at the very bottom asking for "Regex pattern" .
Press enter and it will take you to the match.

Unlike `less` though, you cycle through matches with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> / <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> or with `{` and `}` (see [Searching Commands – Stand-alone GNU Info Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Searching-Commands)).

Comment: This is partially incorrect. You cannot cycle through occurrences of a string using 'n' and 'p'. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580517/29963

Comment: ill have to rethink my life