# Getting error when searching within an info page

Tags: opensuse, pager, info

I'm using the Fish shell on openSUSE Tumbleweed (20200414). I am able to initially search for a string within an info page by typing '/string'. However, when I try to search for the next occurrence using 'n', I receive the following error at the bottom:

```
No 'Next' pointer for this node
```

In addition, searching backwards with 'p' produces a similar message (replaces 'Next' with 'Prev').

Is there a way to fix this? Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything online thus far.

As a workaround, is there a way to change the pager? Info pages seem to ignore $PAGER (I've set it using 'set -Ux PAGER most', which is working just fine on man pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing `info` with `less` and other pagers. `info` doesn't use an
external pager and does not implement the same set of keybindings as
`less` and other pagers do. To jump to the next occurrence of the string press
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> or use other keybindings
as described in [info
manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Searching-Commands). Also, <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> are used for a [completely different purposes](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Node-Commands):

```
n (next-node)
C-NEXT (on DOS/Windows only)

    Select the ‘Next’ node.

    The NEXT key is known as the PgDn key on some keyboards.
p (prev-node)
C-PREVIOUS (on DOS/Windows only)

    Select the ‘Prev’ node.

    The PREVIOUS key is known as the PgUp key on some keyboards.
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the clarification. Part of my confusion stemmed from incorrect info I found online (ex. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370781/how-to-search-info-page-for-keyword)

Comment: Well, the answer you linked to is incorrect.